# FILLER keyword throwing error in external table in oracle

Tags: oracle, sql-loader, external-tables, oracle21c

While creating external table with SQL loader to load data, I used "FILLER" keyword specified as in oracle docs as below.

> A filler field, specified by BOUNDFILLER or FILLER is a data file
> mapped field that does not correspond to a database column. Filler
> fields are assigned values from the data fields to which they are
> mapped. Keep the following in mind regarding filler fields: The syntax
> for a filler field is same as that for a column-based field, except
> that a filler field's name is followed by FILLER.

Here is the link:

[https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/23/sutil/oracle-sql-loader-field-list-contents.html#GUID-EAB9BE96-6F29-4623-9BEF-323C2FE05CB7](https://stackoverflow.com)

But when selecting from external table i am getting below error on the column FIRST_NAME

```
KUP-01005: syntax error: found "identifier": expecting one of: "binary_double, binary_float, comma, char, convert_error, date, defaultif, decimal, double, float, integer, (, lls, lls_compat, no, nullif, oracle_date, oracle_number, position, raw, recnum, ), unsigned, varrawc, varchar, varraw, varcharc, zoned"

KUP-01008: the bad identifier was: FILLER
```

What is causing the issue or i am using it in the wrong way ? But using a Char variable is working fine.

Here is what I did

```
create table etbl
(EMPLOYEE_ID number,
EMAIL varchar2(200),
SALARY number)
organization external 
(
type oracle_loader
default DIRECTORY dir1
access parameters
(
 records delimited by NEWLINE
 skip 1
 logfile 'log.txt'
 badfile 'emp.bad'
 fields terminated by ','
 optionally ENCLOSED by '"'
 MISSING field values are null
 (
 EMPLOYEE_ID char(200),
 FIRST_NAME FILLER,
 FILLER char(200),
 EMAIL char(200),
 FILLER char(200),
 FILLER char(200),
 FILLER char(200),
 SALARY char(200),
 FILLER char(200),
 FILLER  char(200),
 FILLER char(200)
 )
)
location ('emp.txt')
)
reject limit 10;

select * from etbl;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me, it seems that you were mislead by "SQL Loader" *words*.

SQL Loader is utility used to load data from a file stored in directory/folder accessible to you; nice feature is that it can be your own PC, doesn't have to be database server. It is ran by calling `sqlldr.exe` from your operating system command prompt.

External table is a different feature; it is created in database (schema), at SQL level, using the `create table ... organization external` statement, following syntax appropriate for *external tables*. It lets you access data stored in a file which is stored in directory/folder - usually located on a database server - that is also *source* for Oracle object named `directory` that is created by `sys` who then grants appropriate privileges (read and/or write) to database user who will be using it. `type oracle_loader` represents *access driver* used to load data; that's **not** SQL Loader! From [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sutil/oracle-external-tables-concepts.html#GUID-05AA7C84-2C2D-45CE-8F52-392D4A2B4864):

> The access driver runs inside the database server. This behavior is different from SQL*Loader, which is a client program that sends the data to be loaded over to the server.

In the end, it means that parameters you use with SQL*Loader utility (`filler` included) aren't the same as you use with external table.

Comment: So here SQL loader and Oracle_loader are entirely different concept but  do have almost same syntax right ???

Comment: Kind of, yes ... similar, but yet different. Depending on what you use (SQL*Loader or external table), you have to follow syntax which is valid for a chosen *tool*.

Comment: Ok understood . One more doubt is that "FILLER" keyword can be used only in SQL loader syntax but not in External table ? that's why i got error  ?

Comment: That's correct. External tables don't support filler fields.